# Show records in the table with if - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have a plant table and a customer campaign table, I want to show only plants that are not associated with the customer campaign table.

through this if cycle, I would like to get a solution like if it is true not to show the plants that are associated if and it is false shows the plants that are not associated

it's possible?

```
   <?php

    session_start();

    include 'connessione.php';


    $var = true;
    $var = 1;

    $query = mysqli_query($connessione, "

    SELECT *

    FROM store_locator

    INNER JOIN campagne_cliente

    ON store_locator.id = campagne_cliente.impianto_id_campagna");


    if (!$query)

      {
         die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connessione));
      }

    if($var === true){

        echo "email already exists";

    }else{

        echo "ok";

    }
    ?>
```

but if i have only plants associated and nothing plants free i have always ok. 
Why?

Answer (score 0):

USE NOT IN QUERY LIKE THIS....
AM Just Try to understand you,you can manage it according to your table structure.

```
 SELECT * FROM `plant_table` not in (select customer_campaign.plant_id from customer_campaign);
```

Hope This will Help You.
Thanks

I got this result:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'not in (select campagne_cliente.impianto_id_campagna from campagne_cliente)' at line 2
```

this is a query:

```
 SELECT * FROM `store_locator` 
 not in 
 (select campagne_cliente.impianto_id_campagna
 from campagne_cliente);
```

Comment: SELECT *

FROM store_locator not in

INNER JOIN campagne_cliente

ON store_locator.id = campagne_cliente.impianto_id_campagna

Answer (score 0):

Correct:

```
<?php

session_start();

include 'connessione.php';

$id = $_SESSION['id'];

$query_string = "SELECT * FROM store_locator WHERE store_locator.id NOT IN (SELECT impianto_id_campagna FROM campagne_cliente);
";

$query = mysqli_query($connessione, $query_string);

?>



<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){ ?>

<?php echo $row['id'] ;?>

<?php } ?>
```